# How to move or nudge notes in Guitar Pro 7?

Tags: guitar-pro

I want to nudge some of the notes just a tiny bit for aesthetic reasons. For instance, I want to nudge the first eighth-notes: `[g, f, e, f]` just a little bit to the right, mostly because I don't want the stem of the first two g-notes to overlap.

| Comment | Image |
| --- | --- |
| AS IS (From Guitar Pro) | [image: Original score] |
| TO BE (Photo manipulated) | [image] |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I searched through all instances of the words "move", "moving", "position", and "placement" in the manual (including words that contain those words), and none of those instances was about hand-positioning individual elements graphically. I conclude that this is not possible in Guitar Pro 7. The only visual/graphical aspect I've found in the program that can be point-and-clicked and moved is barlines in Design mode. Everything else is auto-generated by the program, and the only way to adjust the visual layout of anything is via textual/numerical data entry in various dialogs, or by changing the musical meaning of objects. It's not a drag-anything-anywhere sort of application. You enter your musical and textual content along with layout-related hopes and dreams (aka "settings"), and the program does the layout. It's good for a lot of things, and for many things it's the best.

Comment: Thanks. I went through the manual myself, and didn't find anything about what I want. I think I will try to find a MusicXML editor or similar to modify the layout of the sheet music to my liking. Guitar Pro is my go to editor for creating sheet music because it's blazing fast for transcribing music. It comes with many "what you need" features instead of "nice to have features", focusing on usability! Thanks for looking into it though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this feature exists for version 7 or not, but in version 8, this is a simple task, just click on Taha from the View menu and then you can customize everything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will see if I'm able to test it using Guitar Pro 8.